# how OTA programming for arduino using gsm can be done?

Tags: arduino, gsm, ota

I am doing a project on OTA programming of Arduino at remote place so I need GSM along with Arduino, so how can we do OTA with gsm for Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking how you can remotely control an Arduino with your phone, right?

I suggest using Bluetooth for this, as it is build into every phone nowadays. You'll still have to buy a module to allow the Arduio to communicate via bluetooth. An example of such a module is the HTC-06, wich can be bought online for less then $10 and for wich there is an exellent tutorial [over at instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/).

The phone side of the story depends on what kind of device you're using, [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) is the official Android documentation, [this](https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/) seems to be the Apple documentation.

Alternatively, if you don't want to write everyting yourself, you can use an app like Tinkernut does is [one of his videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXs7S048eIo).

Comment: Not using phone..using GSM SIM900 module.

Comment: Why didn't you specify that in your question? There is also some other information missing, like what information you want to send and to what device you want to send it.

Comment: I Mean i need to update frimware of arduino which is  at remote location using gsm sim900.frimware would be in the server where this sim900 would be used to download that code(frimware) from server to arduino and get  arduino updated with the frimware.