# How to acknowledge arduino using an LED when a call recieve in smartphone

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm completely new to the arduino controlling and programming.

I want to get signal my android smartphone , When a call receive to smartphone I want to acknowledge my Arduino uno board by blinking a LED.

Then if I want to take a call using a physical button I have to answer the call or reject it.

Simply I want to send digital signals from my smartphone to Arduino board and I want to receive the analog button press as response to the phone call(Whether answer/ignore)

I connect phone and Arduino via Bluetooth

This is the Where I have struggling right now.

I need some help on this please!!

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that I wrote an answer that fits this question a couple of days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39315972/5517612), this is an edited version of it:

You'll have to buy a module to allow the Arduio to communicate via bluetooth. An example of such a module is the HTC-06, wich can be bought online for less then $10 and for which there is an exellent tutorial [over at instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/).

The phone side of the story is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), in the official Android documentation. It is sometimes convenient to test with a terminal on your phone, I used [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Qwerty.BluetoothTerminal).
I have some code laying around that can send some data between the Arduino and my phone, I can post it later today if you'd like that.

Alternatively, if you don't want to write everyting yourself, you can use an app like Tinkernut does is [one of his videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXs7S048eIo).

Comment: I connected the phone but my need is to send acknowledgements to Arduino when a call came to my smartphone and after that send signal to my smartphone to answer the phone

Comment: Please if you can post the post the code appreciate it.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you were having problems connecting your phone to an Arduino. You're really asking how to "detect" that a phone call was received, right? Do you have a working Android app? (that code was about connecting with bluetooth, but you've got that part figured out I see)

Comment: By the way thanks for your help.I got the solution from tinkernut video that smart watch thing it really helped me!